# How to put Shopping cart on the right sidebar in checkout?

Tags: checkout, cart, magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart

I want to put the shopping cart at the right side of of my horizontal checkout.
Something like this [image]

Answer (score 5):

When I wanted to show the cart on the sidebar, my first instinct was to use the existing `checkout/cart_sidebar` block in Magento, but I have found a better solution which uses the `checkout/onepage_review_info` block instead.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Just add this to your local.xml:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <!-- This sets the template to 2column-right.phtml. -->
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right"/>

    <reference name="right">


        <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout_review_sidebar" output="toHtml" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
                <label>Items Before</label>
            </block>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
                <label>Items After</label>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        <!-- This block is only for information; we don't want the "Place Order" button showing.
            <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
        -->
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 4):

1St:first change `this page layout 2columns-left.phtml to 2columns-right.phtml`
Chekout how to change page layout:http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-change-page-layout-in-magento/

2nd:`create local.xml under app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout/`
**put this code:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_ri" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but how to change the pay page layout ?

Comment: didn't worked..

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <layout version="0.1.0">
>   <default>
>       <reference name="right">
>               <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
>                   <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
>                   <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
>                   <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
>                   <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
>                   <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
>                   <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
>
>               </block>
>       </reference>    
>
>   </default>
> </layout>
> ```

Paste this code in your local.xml. It display cart in right side bar. but, for perfection you have to resize your right sidebar size and (dependent phtml files in above code)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="right">
    <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
        <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
        <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action> 
    </block>
    </reference>        
</default>
</layout>
```

Paste this code in your `local.xml.` It display cart in right side bar. but, for perfection you have to resize your right sidebar  and edit dependent phtml files in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Before apply the above codes Go to admin panel click on
"System->Configuration->sales->Checkout". Under the  Shopping Cart Sidebar
section, choose "yes" in "Display Shopping Cart Sidebar" dropdown box.